# How to display data from sqlite in spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display my data which is present in database. but I could not able be display this data in ui. I use the spinner but it does not work..how to sort this..where is the my mistake?

```
Spinner spr;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       spr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
       // ArrayAdapter<Contact>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cn.getName());
        }

        loadData();
    }
    private void loadData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DataBaseHandler db=new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> label=db.getAllContacts();

         for (Contact cn : label) {
             String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();


             ArrayAdapter<Contact>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,label);

         spr.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
      }
}


//package com.example.newdemo;

public class Contact {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;

    // Empty constructor
    public Contact(){

    }
    // constructor
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }

    // constructor
    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Spinner want to display only name or all data of contacts i.e. id, name and phone number.

Comment: i want to display data which i display in log cat i.e id name no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
    Spinner spr;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

    loadData();
}
private void loadData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<Contact> label=db.getAllContacts();
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (Contact cn : label) {
         String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
         nameList.add(cn.getName());    
     }
     ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList );
     spr.setAdapter(adapter);
  } }
```

if you want to show name in spinner.

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you then you should accept or vote up this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your knowledge,  It can also work without taking ArrayList of String Type.

For that, you just need to override toString method in your **Contact** class and return contact name there

For example, add the following method in Contact class

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return _name;
    }
```

No changes in your **loadData**() method.